# "Elevation" word usage

Tags: word-meaning

I read this line in a book:

*"The general elevation of the Deccan plateau is from the West to East, which is proved by the pattern of the flow of the rivers, which flow from West to East."*

Shouldn't the elevation be East to West, as elevation means increase in height? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Wikipedia says "The eastern Deccan Plateau is at a lower elevation spanning the southeastern coast of India."

Comment: What book? The expression "the elevation is from west to east" doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: [*The **average elevation** of the Deccan Plateau is two thousand feet above sea level.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22elevation+of+the+Deccan+plateau+is%22) That's a valid usage, but yours isn't - ***regardless of which direction corresponds to increasing elevation***.

Comment: "elevation means increase in height" - no, as a **noun** it just means "height". An "elevator" will take you down as well as up.

Comment: Note also that usages such as *The elevation of beatified saints above ordinary mortals* can be paraphrased as ***the increasing / increased [metaphorical] height / the raising up***, it can't naturally be used in that way in your literal context.

Comment: The writer obviously intended the clause 'The general elevation of the Deccan plateau is from the West to East,' to mean that the plateau is most elevated in the West and least elevated in the East, otherwise the remainder of their sentence, intended as a proof of the main clause, would be illogical. However, I think they could have used a less ambiguous clause to convey that thought.

Comment: @James agreed.  Like "The Deccan plateau slopes down from the West to the East..."

Comment: @JamesK India: Physical Environment, NCERT for 11th class, page 16

Comment: @James exactly!

Comment: There seems to be a slight misquoting  Should be "The general elevation of the
plateau is from the west to the east, which is
also proved by the pattern of the flow of rivers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a rather badly expressed sentence.

Normally "elevation" just means "height". We might say "The plateau has an elevation of 500m".

We wouldn't say "the general elevation is from the west to the east". Clearly what the author wanted to express was "The land generally slopes down from the west to the east."

This use of elevation may have a particular meaning in Indian English, or it may just be a badly written sentence. It is possible the author intended to write "The general elevation is [between  500 and 1000m and the land slopes down] from the west to the east"  but the part in brackets was edited out for some reason.

Similar ambiguity appears later:

> The general elevation of the Central
>   Highlands ranges between 700-1,000 m above
>   the mean sea level and it slopes towards the
>   north and northeastern directions.

It is not clear if the land slopes down, or up, toward the north.